# What difference of marked relays on scheme?

Tags: pcb-design, relay, schematics

I have two relays that marked as red and orange.
What is the difference between them?

And what relays (SMD) I should use to create pcb? 
[image]

Thanks for answer.

Comment: Tyler, I know this. But one coil part have triangle, and another doesnt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this web site](http://www.electronic-symbols.com/electric-electronic-symbols/relay-electromagnet-symbols.htm) it is a "Step relay Mechanical interlock relay".

As far as the contact for K2 goes, I would guess its a 'make before break'.

Comment: thanks a lot, can you help me to choose datasheet for that element please?

Comment: If it is indeed a Mechanically Interlocked Relay, you would need to know what (how) it is mechanically interlocked before you can find a replacement relay. The information needed to do that has not been provided. If you had a bill of material or a picture of it, someone might be able to help.

Comment: Does mechanical interlock relay mean that we have relay with mechanical button?